# Opitimizing 2 functions written in Python

Tags: python, optimization, time-complexity

I would like to decrease the time complexity of this function. When I have like 1020 KB, it takes a few seconds to complete these functions. The example of input is `["1001010", "1000001"]`

```
def bits_to_rgb(data):
    bits = [255 if x == "1" else 0 for x in ''.join(data)]
    full_bits = []

    for i in bits:
         full_bits.extend([i, i, i])

    return full_bits
```

output

```
rgb = bits_to_rgb(["1001010", "1000001"])
rgb
>> [255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255]
```

As I said I would like to decrease the time complexity. I tried to yield the result and then call `list()` later on but the time difference was not significant.

Comment: Try having a single iteration with fewer memory allocations. `return list(chain.from_iterable((255, 255, 255) if x == "1" else (0, 0, 0) for x in ''.join(data)))
` You will need to do `from itertools import chain`

Comment: Are you sure this takes multiple seconds to run "with 1000 bits"?

Answer (score 0):

The lower bound for this I think will be `O(n)` where `n` is the total number of bits. You can optimize on reducing reducing number of operations needed to compute the end result, for e.g, removing the `join` operation.

```
def bits_to_rgb(data):
    full_bits = []

    for bits in data:
        for i in bits:
            full_bits.extend([255, 255, 255] if i == '1' else [0, 0, 0])

    return full_bits
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is doing everything inside a single loop

```
def bits_to_rgb(data):
  full_bits = []
  
  for x in ''.join(data):
    full_bits.extend([255*(x == "1")]*3)

  return full_bits
```

It may look tricky but keep in mind that:

- In Python a boolean acts like 0 or 1 according if it's false or true respectively when multiplied to a number.
- when you multiply a list like [255] by n in repeats itself n times, i.e `[255]*3 = [255, 255, 255]`

Still, as Jarmod said, it's weird that it takes several seconds to run a relatively simple function like that.